# fisher discriminant computation time

Tags: performance, lisp, classification

I've recently implemented Fisher's Linear Discriminant (FLD) in Lisp. Hitherto I've been using samples of dim(<10), with populations of order 10 with which FLD executed immediately. This morning I used real-world data with dim(5) and populations of order 10<sup>4</sup>, and the program has been running for a few hours now on my AMD Athlon(tm) II Dual-Core M320 × 2 laptop. Here are the sizes of the files I'm using:

```
 $ wc output_sig.txt
 13000  65000 627677 output_sig.txt
 $ wc output_bkg.txt
 13000  65000 644621 output_bkg.txt
```

In view of the above, how does the computation time of FLD scale with sample size and dimensionality? Is a few hours computation time to be expected here?

Comment: Thanks, I'll insert print statements and create a log file. I may need a dedicated PC.

Comment: You may want to look at installing a profiler to inspect percent time spent in each function. The time macro may also be of some help.

Comment: Thanks, I'm in the process of installing SLIME- emacs seems to have attractive profilers.

Comment: Bracket: do an asymptotic analysis of the algorithm itself, then investigate the costs for each of your access/write times. That should give you the deepest understanding of what's going on. Also, you might want to post your code. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to use a bit of CPU time to get T(n)->infinity for the asymptotic part, but it's definitely worth it. I could iterate those steps also.

Comment: This question is somewhat in an ineffective state because it refers to the asymptotic performance of some code, without showing that code. There could be various confounding factors which blow up its performance.

Comment: I'm currently installing github, so the code should be uploaded soon. Also, using slime, I compiled the code making the run 50 mins give or take a few minutes. But it would be nice to make the code run faster, especially for larger data sets.

Comment: SBCL (http://www.sbcl.org/) can compile quite fast code. It might be worth checking it out as well.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the code: LDA is basically a generalized eigenvalue problem, so the problem is solved if one uses a sufficiently efficient linear algebra routine. Handwritten routines in LISP will usually be not very efficient, so I recommend using a LAPACK wrapper such as Matlisp.

Comment: Thanks, I've actually written a small matrix library myself, which I can compile to C using ECL.

Comment: Coding it in native C is only part of the package, the BLAS libraries with the primitive matrix operations should also optimally be fine-tuned for the processor to minimize cache misses. The ATLAS system is an attempt to achieve this: http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/ Unless you're very well versed in numerical linear algebra, this is not a part I'd try coding from scratch.